# Fabric Crashlytics for Android not working

Tags: android, crashlytics

I’ve followed the installation tutorial step by step for an Android app.

All seems fine, but after a couple of hours I don’t get to enter the dashboard (always redirected to the installation tutorial).
I guess that means my app have not been detected yet. It is supposed to be ready after a few minutes.

Enabling debug mode, everything looks good:

```
06-01 10:56:12.697 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Attempting to send crash report at time of crash...
    06-01 10:56:12.837 4410-9967/? E/SQLiteLog: (284) automatic index on crash_info_summary(package_name_touched)
    06-01 10:56:13.067 989-3341/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.app.videoplayer/.videowall.TranscodeService in 1000ms
    06-01 10:56:13.787 989-1335/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.widgetapp.at.hero.accuweather/.WeatherClockScreenService in 10276ms
    06-01 10:56:13.787 989-1335/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.sec.android.widgetapp.at.hero.accuweather/.WeatherClockService in 20275ms
    06-01 10:56:14.507 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Adding single file 592FD68C000C-0001-268F-1112AA20B096.cls to report 592FD68C000C-0001-268F-1112AA20B096
    06-01 10:56:14.507 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Sending report to: https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/android/apps/com.minsait.visitaunica.desa/reports
    06-01 10:56:14.977 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Create report request ID: null
    06-01 10:56:14.977 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Result was: 202
    06-01 10:56:14.977 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 592FD68C000C-0001-268F-1112AA20B096
    06-01 10:56:14.977 9871-9899/com.mypackage.test.desa D/CrashlyticsCore: Removing report at /data/data/com.minsait.visitaunica.desa/files/.Fabric/com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core/fatal-sessions/592FD68C000C-0001-268F-1112AA20B096.cls
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you share your snapshot of build.gradle file, AndroidManifest and application or activity class which you are using..?

Comment: If your app is not listed in crashlytics dashboard means, there is no crash detected so far.

Try this call in your application/activity class
if (true) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Testing my first crash...");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems that the issue was a wrong internal state in their DB. Also happened 2 more times with other projects.

Contacting the support team was the solution. They replied very quickly and were very kind by the way.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Glad we were able to help out. In general, we need a build and run of the app in order to activate it. Having a crash early may not give us enough time to activate the app. You can also enabled debug mode to try and get things to activate if you're stuck: https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem; even though you haven't added the fabric, apparently you have to remove it within the manifest:

```
<meta-data
tools:node="remove"
android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, I always recommend installing Fabric.io using the build in IDE plugin.

You can find out how to install that here:

https://fabric.io/downloads/android

Comment: Note: Crashlytics will soon become the primary crash reporter for Firebase. If you aren't already using Crash Reporting to report crashes and non-fatal errors in your app, we recommend using Crashlytics.

Comment: Google bought Crashlytics and now wants you to move crash reports back to Crashlytics from Firebase. https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/summary?ref=fb

Comment: Removed that comment, remember them saying once that they were moving away from Fabric :P